# Getting multiple value of checkbox in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to get the multiple value of my checkbox with the jQuery but with my code I got double value.

If I pick `Apple` and `Manggo` and when I submit the form I get value of `Apple` `Apple` `Manggo`.

A lot of tutorial use `.click` function. Since I have more function I want to use it outside the `const submit =() =>{}`

How do I fix this multiple value ?

```js
let fruit_temp = [];
$('input[name="chk_fruit"]').change(function() {
  $('input[name="chk_fruit"]:checked').each(function() {
    fruit_temp.push($(this).val());
  });
});

const submit = () => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  //more formData
  formData.append('Fruit', fruit_temp);

  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-30">
  <label><b>Favourite Fruit</b></label><br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Apple"> Apple</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Manggo"> Manggo</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Honeydew"> Honeydew</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="chk_fruit" value="Orange"> Orange</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- more form field -->
    <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you loop through using `.each`, you are grabbing all of the values that are currently selected and pushing them into the `fruit_temp` array. However, you are not resetting the value of `fruit_temp`, so you are pushing more and more with each checkbox. All you you need to do is clear the array with each change:

```
let fruit_temp = [];
$('input[name="chk_fruit"]').change(function() {
  fruit_temp = [];
  $('input[name="chk_fruit"]:checked').each(function() {
    fruit_temp.push($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Comment: As a side note, you seem new to jQuery. Look into wrapping your code in `$(document).ready(function() { // code here });`. This will let the browser build the page and locate all of the elements and their properties before trying to attach the `.change` events to them.

Comment: your explanation is great! thank you. I understood better now

Comment: yup you are right I new to jQuery I'm still learning :) yup I already have the `$(document).ready(function() { // code here });`  thnk you for reminding :)

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
let fruit_temp = [];
$('input[name="chk_fruit"]').change(function() {
  fruit_temp = []; // reset your variable before adding another checked items
  $('input[name="chk_fruit"]:checked').each(function() {
    fruit_temp.push($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Simply reset your variable before adding latest checked items into your array. `fruit_temp = [];` on your `change` event will do the work.